# Submit Page to Privious Page visited

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, session, hyperlink

I have Contact Us link on footer of my MVC Application.

On calling page contains form to submit feedback..

when valid form will submit the i want to redirect to the page from which that Contact Us link is called.

How will maintain that privious link. I can not make use of history becuase it contains the validations if the form fails it show error and after submiting valid form then privious history is same i.e contact us form.

Should I use session to store the privious form url or Is there any another way to do this?

Comment: probably you can use querystring like `?Reidrecturl="/xxx.aspx"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Forms Authentication integration in the ASP.NET MVC Internet Application template, it handles exactly this scenario.

What you probably want to do is have your "Contact us" link point to:-

`/ContactUs?returnUrl={the current URL}`

You can build that like:-

```
@Html.ActionLink(
  "Contact us", "Contact", "Home", new { returnUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery })
```

You can then capture that in an action method parameter server side. The parameter will survive the form POST, even if you have a server-side validation failure in the meantime.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ContactUs(ContactUsModel model, string returnUrl)
{
  if (ModelStat.IsValid)
  {
    // Do whatever you need to do with the ContactUsModel

    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl)
    {
      return Redirect(returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
      return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
  }

  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I am getting null value to returnUrl but it will show on browser. I am using <a href="/ContactUs?returnUrl=@Request.Url.PathAndQuery"></a>

Comment: Can you post your view and controller code in your question above?